# Split array element lines and combine into one line

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, split

I have an array element which is split over three lines , I want to put all three line into one line 
Want it to look like this

```
Error deleting file data during scheduled task Delete Path: C:\temp\Data Error: 0x80654005 - Access is denied.
```

I have tried below but it still print in separate lines

```
$logerror[0][0..70] -join ''
```

Array element

```
>$logerror[0]
Error deleting file data during scheduled task
Delete Path: C:\temp\Data
Error: 0x80654005 - Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is a bit unclear. So if the text is **in** an array but the three lines are just a string with linebreaks, try:

```
$logerror[0] -replace ([System.Environment]::NewLine," ")
```

If the text is an array, in which each line is its own array element:

```
[string]::Join(" ",$logerror[0])
```

Comment: Holy crap , your first solution was spot on ! Can you clarify it in steps . Is there a way I can add a separator before the join of new line ?

Comment: The blank (" ") is the separator, you can replace that with anything you want.

Comment: I got that . Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(logerror[0] -split '\n') -join ' '
```